# Filter set of sets based on boolean expression

Tags: scala

I have a set of sets as follows:

```
val s =  Set(Set(), Set(1, 3), Set(2), Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3),
  Set(3), Set(1, 2, 3), Set(1))
```

which I would like to filter in a manner similar to this one:

```
s.filter(subset => subset contains !1 && 2)
```

where `!1 && 2` would be some arbitrary boolean expression supplied to me.

from which I would get back:

```
Set(Set(2), Set(2, 3))
```

For the sake of the example I chose `Int` but it would be some arbitrary type.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by formula.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but I think `!subset(1) && subset(2)` is about the best you're going to get.

Comment: `!1 && 2` isn't a formula though. It doesn't mean anything in the language. `contains` accepts a specific element, so the only way to use it is to break it up.

Comment: The concept of "formula" would represent an arbitrary boolean expression, I edited the question for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear on what you mean by "formula". However, it seems obvious that you want to parameterize a `filter` operation somehow.

In Scala, we typically do that by passing blocks of code. For instance, in this (simpleminded) example, `keep` and `discard` are your two "formulas":

```
def processSet[T](s: Set[Set[T]], keep: => T, discard: => T): Set[Set[T]] = {
  s.filter { subset => (subset contains keep) && !(subset contains discard) }
}
```

You could then call that function as follows:

```
processSet(Set(Set(10, 20), Set(1, 2), Set(10, 100), Set(10, 20, 30)), 10, 30)
// returns: Set(Set(10, 20), Set(10, 100))
```

I'm not sure whether that gets close to what you want or  not.

Comment: The thing is I don't know the "formula" in advance it could be an "and" or an "or" or any combination forming a boolean expression.

Comment: Then have the caller pass the entire "formula" in as a block of code. The block can receive a subset and determine whether to keep or discard it.

There's no `eval` in Scala. ;-)

Comment: Yup, thanks I think that's what I'm going to have to do.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific example in the question, you're close. You just need to separate the tests for 1 and 2. Also, because of the way the value s has been created, you have to explicitly convert the subsets with `toSet`:

```
val s = Set(Set(), Set(1, 3), Set(2), Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3), 
            Set(3), Set(1, 2, 3), Set(1))

s.filter{ subset => 
    !(subset.toSet contains 1) && (subset.toSet contains 2)
}
```

If the explicit conversion isn't desirable, you can supply a type for s, as in one of the other answers:

```
val s:Set[Set[Int]] = Set(Set(), Set(1, 3), Set(2), Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3), 
                          Set(3), Set(1, 2, 3), Set(1))

s.filter{ subset => 
    !(subset contains 1) && (subset contains 2)
}
```

Your approach will already work for an arbitrary "formula", as long as `filter` receives a function (above, an [anonymous function](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html)) that returns a `Boolean` value.

A useful way to parameterize filters is to use [curried functions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/currying.html):

```
def requirements(x: Int, y: Int)(subset: Set[Int]): Boolean = {
    !(subset contains x) && (subset contains 2)
}

s.filter{ requirements(1, 2)_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (scala 2.11.4):

```
val s:Set[Set[Int]] = Set(Set(), Set(1, 3), Set(2), Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3),Set(3), Set(1, 2, 3), Set(1))

s.filter(subset => !subset.contains(1) && subset.contains(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used spire's [Bool](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/algebra/Bool.scala) to get the job done:

```
import spire.algebra._
import spire.implicits._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit def PredicateBooleanAlgebra[T] = new Bool[T => Boolean] {
      def one: T => Boolean = _ => true
      def zero: T => Boolean = _ => false
      def and(a: T => Boolean, b: T => Boolean): T => Boolean = x => a(x) && b(x)
      def or(a: T => Boolean, b: T => Boolean): T => Boolean = x => a(x) || b(x)
      def complement(a: T => Boolean) = x => !a(x)
    }

    def contains1(s: Set[Int]) = s contains 1
    def contains2(s: Set[Int]) = s contains 2

    val s = Set(1, 2, 3).subsets.map(_.toSet).toSet
    println(s.filter(~(contains1 _) & (contains2 _)))
  }
}
```

Comment: ..And you killed a fly with a bazooka :)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question, but this is exactly what I was looking for.